# Relation between mean of the hypergeometric distribution and binomial

Tags: distributions, binomial-distribution, expected-value, hypergeometric-distribution

The mean of the hypergeometric distribution is:

$n \frac{K}{N}$

where:

- $n$ is the number of draws
- $K$ is the number of successes
- N is the size of the finite population.

As the population size, $N$, goes to infinity, I would expect to have a situation with "replacement", and have the mean to converge to the mean of the Binomial distribution, but instead the mean converges to 0 (see the formula).

Why is this the case?

Comment: By keeping $K$ constant, the proportion of success states in the population grows vanishingly small as $N$ grows large.

Comment: You have the same expectation for a binomial distribution with parameters $n$ and $p=\frac{K}{N}$.  What happens when $N$ increases while $n$ and $K$ do not?

Comment: Thanks @whuber-  if you write that as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 2):

The mean of the hypergeometric distribution can be interpreted as the finite sampling equivalent of $\mu = np$ from the binomial, taking $p=\frac{K}{N}$.  The variance can be expressed as $\sigma^2 = \left(n\frac{K}{N}\frac{N-K}{N}\right)\left(\frac{N-n}{N-1}\right)$, which is exactly analogous to the binomial $\sigma^2=np(1-p)$, except that there is a correction factor of $\frac{N-n}{N-1}$ added.  So, in the limit as $N \to \infty$ and $\frac{K}{N} \to p$, the hypergeometric's moments approach the binomial.  It's better to show via a generating function approach (several are possible, I think the easiest is the pgf) that the random variable itself (rather than the moment sequence) converges.